# RenderSettings customReflection texture has invalid type, 2D given while only CUBE is supported. Custom reflection texture will not be used

Tags: unity-game-engine

so I started an unity project w ps1 graphics style, and it been smth like 2 days I have this error but the game still working kinda fine, can someone explain me why this happening? Thanks!
(Im not using URP)

Full error :

```
RenderSettings customReflection texture has invalid type, 2D given while only CUBE is supported. Custom reflection texture will not be used in UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_RestoreLastOpenedScenes ()
```

Comment: [Texture Types](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/TextureTypes.html) Sounds like the texture type is incorrectly set.

Comment: hijinxbassist what does it means ? and how to fix the error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Texture 2D Import Settings`, change `Texture Shape` from `2D` to `CUBE`.

In your project, click on your texture.  Import settings are found in the inspector.

[image: Texture Shape Default]

[image: Texture Shape Cube]

> Cube defines the Texture as a cubemap. You could use this for Skyboxes or Reflection Probes
> , for example. This type is only available with the Default, Normal Map, and Single Channel Texture types.

From the [Texture Shape Reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporter.html#textureshape) of Texture Importer Documentation.